# Best practices for HTTP 400 response security

Tags: api, security, websecurity

For example we have REST endpoint (or even simple endpoint). Someone passes incorrect payload and receives 400 error code in response.

How detailed response should be in case of some field exceeded it’s expected length from the security point of view? Should we open validation details to user and return in a message field something like: “You exceeded length of zip code. Max value is 5. ” Or details should be hidden from user and HTTP status code should be enough?

Comment: It depends. If the validation rules are publicly available – that's ok to provide detailed error message. But exposing internal business rules might be (and most likely is) a vulnerability.

Comment: Just think about the person how you'd write a client for your API and need to debug these errors. Give the client enough information to debug.

Answer (score 0):

- On the **client-side** use handy validation messages such as "The ZIP Code must have 5 digits"
- On the **server-side** respond with an empty 400

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#error-handling

For example:

```js
const AuthError = 1
const ValidationError = 2

const isId = value =>
  isString(value)
    && value.length === StandardIdCharLength
    && /^[\w-]*$/.test(value)

async function resetPasswordPost(request, response) {
  try {
    const body = await jsonBody(request) // throws ValidationError

    if (!(
      body
      && Object.keys(body).length === 3
      && isPassword(body.password)
      && isId(body.userId)
      && isId(body.token)
    ))
      throw ValidationError

    if (!await passwordResetTokenExists(body.token, body.userId))
      throw AuthError

    // …
    sendOk(response)
  }

  catch (error) {
    switch (error) {
      case AuthError:
        sendUnauthorized(response)
        break

      case ValidationError:
        sendBadRequest(response)
        break

      default:
        sendInternalServerError(response)
    }
  }
}

function sendBadRequest(response) {
    response.statusCode = 400
    response.end()
}
```